# Story where small girl pushes a chair against a wall to reach an oil painting that bleeds when she scratches it

Tags: story-identification, horror

I remember the scene very vividly from television, possibly a mini-series from the 70's or 80's. A small girl enters a dark hallway with baroque style furniture. Her attention is held by a portrait painted in oil on the wall. She pushes the chair against the wall and climbs atop the seat. Without much of an expression she rakes the fingers of one hand down the painting. Blood oozes from the painting. The child may or may not have screamed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it possibly by [Picture Mommy Dead](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060831/) (1961)? I haven't seen it myself, but [one of the reviews](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060831/reviews) seems to describe something very similar happening.

Here is [another review](http://www.kindertrauma.com/?p=36379) that seems to describe something similar. I am trying to find a video of the scene, but the who movie seems to be rather elusive.

**EDIT**: I have found the clip http://www.tcm.com/mediaroom/video/1076481/Picture-Mommy-Dead-Movie-Clip-Murder-.html

Comment: I also seem to have found the full movie on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqHH88ha30E).

Comment: Fascinating! I remembered certain aspects of the scene differently, but I was obviously very upset by this as a child. I'm an enormous fan of horror and glad to finally put a scene with a title! Thank you so much!